# table with sales and quantity of products - add column that count the products

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregation

i have this table:
[image: my table]

i want to add column:count - that i can see for each product how many sales were, like this:

[image]

i try like this:

```
update #t
set quantity = (select count(*) from #t group by product)
```

it is not good because it's return more then 1 value

Comment: Create a view instead. (And avoid data inconsistency.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
sum(quantity)  over (partition by product)
```

Or you can correlated your subquery :

```
update t1
       set t1.quantity = (select sum(t.quantity) 
                          from #t as t  
                          where t.product = t1.product
                         )
from #t t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(quantity) over(partition by product) cnt
from mytable t
```

As suggested by jarlh, a better idea than updating would be to create a view, so you don't need to worry about maintaining integrity of the derived column:

```
create view myview
select
    t.*,
    sum(quantity) over(partition by product) cnt
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
update #t
    set quantity = new_quantity
    from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by product) as new_quantity
          from #t t
         ) t;
```

You should probably do this when you *create* the temporary table, but you can update the value afterwards as well.

Comment: @M.R . . . Not a useful comment.